# Uncheck one box unchecks all boxes

Tags: android, checkboxpreference

I have an activity that extends PreferenceActivity.
I have in settings.xml 3 checkboxpreferences. If I uncheck the first checkbox, the other 2 to uncheck.
What is the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use checkbox.toggle()

First make a onClickListener:

```
Checkbox chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

       }
   }
);
```

Then change the other checkboxes:

```
    CheckBox chk1, chk2;

        chk1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        chk2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
```

and:

```
            if(chk1.isChecked()){
                chk1.toggle();
            }

            if(chk2.isChecked()){
                chk2.toggle();
            }
```